# infectious disease probblem about Possion process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

A disease has an incubation period from infection to onset. the number of infected people in $(0,t]$ is expressed in $N (T)$. Suppose $\left \{ N(t):t\ge0 \right \} $ is Poisson process with parameter $\lambda$. The incubation period of each infected person is independent (also independent of $\left \{ N(t) \right \} $  )and has the density function $f (x)=2x,0<x<1$ .Try to get The density function of the onset time of the first patient;

Now I have computed the onset time of the first infectious person,$S_1$ is the happening time of first infectious person,from the property of Possion process, we know $S_1$ follows $\Gamma(1,\lambda)=E(\lambda)$ distribution,X is the incubation period. Set the $\xi=S_1+X$, use the addtive of two independent random variables to get the density funtion of X. But in this question we can know that the first patient maybe not the first infectious person, I am stuck now.Thanks for watching and hope to get help from you smart guys.

Comment: Can you clarify what $f$ is? Is it the density function of the incubation time? Why this choice? The difficulty here is that your system does not have the memoryless property.

Comment: How are you distinguishing between an "infected person" and a "patient"?

Comment: f is the density function of incubation period of a infected person

Comment: a infected person will need some time ,i.e.the incubation period to become ill